# Visual Studio Community 2015 and TFS 2015 Express - Get relations between work items, changesets and labels

Tags: vb.net, rest, api, tfs

I'm trying to create an application (VB.NET, Winform project) that obtains, starting from a work item ID, all the changesets and the labels relative to the work item.

I've tried to get all the data with this code:

```
Dim c As New VssCredentials()
Dim conn As New VssConnection(New Uri(URI_PROJECTS), c)

'get all changesets
Dim tfvcClient As TfvcHttpClient = conn.GetClient(Of TfvcHttpClient)
Dim changesetTemp As List(Of TfvcChangesetRef)
Dim changesetList As New List(Of TfvcChangesetRef)
Dim firstCycle As Boolean = True
Dim stopCycle As Boolean = False
Dim lastChangesetId As Integer = -1
While Not stopCycle
    If Not firstCycle Then
        Dim criteria As New TfvcChangesetSearchCriteria()
        criteria.ToId = lastChangesetId
        changesetTemp = tfvcClient.GetChangesetsAsync(project:=PROJ_NAME, top:=256, searchCriteria:=criteria).Result
        criteria = Nothing
    Else
        firstCycle = False
        changesetTemp = tfvcClient.GetChangesetsAsync(project:=PROJ_NAME, top:=256).Result
    End If
    If changesetTemp.Count > 0 Then
        If lastChangesetId = -1 Then
            changesetList.AddRange(changesetTemp)
        Else
            changesetList.AddRange(changesetTemp.GetRange(1, changesetTemp.Count - 1))
        End If
        lastChangesetId = changesetTemp.Last.ChangesetId
        If changesetTemp.Count < 256 Then
            stopCycle = True
        End If
    End If
End While

'get all work item linked to changesets
For i As Integer = 0 To changesetList.Count - 1
    Dim changeset As TfvcChangeset = tfvcClient.GetChangesetAsync(changesetList(i).ChangesetId, top:=1, includeDetails:=False, includeWorkItems:=True).Result
Next

'get all labels linked to changesets
Dim req As New TfvcLabelRequestData
req.MaxItemCount = 2000
Dim tfvcLbl As List(Of TfvcLabelRef) = tfvcClient.GetLabelsAsync(project:=PROJ_NAME, requestData:=req, top:=2000).Result
Dim item(tfvcLbl.Count - 1) As TfvcItem
For i As Integer = 0 To tfvcLbl.Count - 1
    item(i) = tfvcClient.GetLabelItemsAsync(tfvcLbl(i).Id).Result(0)
Next
```

Everything works, but the software is really slow, it needs about 8 minutes to complete.

How can I speed it? At present I haven't found quicker functions.

Comment: Put in some Stopwatch to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Which part is the slowest? Is it `get all changesets? If you make $top to 100, how's the speed? You may try to use TFS REST API in Postman to see how's the performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changesets?view=vsts-rest-5.0.

Comment: Hello,
slowest lines are:

    Dim changeset As TfvcChangeset = tfvcClient.GetChangesetAsync(changesetList(i).ChangesetId, top:=1, includeDetails:=False, includeWorkItems:=True).Result

[min: 23 ms, average: 46 ms, max: 1363 ms]

    item(i) = tfvcClient.GetLabelItemsAsync(tfvcLbl(i).Id).Result(0)

[min: 177 ms, average: 257 ms, max: 2988 ms]

Regards

Comment: The final purpose of my application is to have all the labels associated to a precise work item, but I haven't found specific functions for obtain it. This is the reason why I use all these functions and these cycles. If there's an alternative I would be happy to try it.

Comment: @IvanP Labels? Do you mean work item fields? You may check work item api here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1